# How do I compare values of integers inside strings using MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I wrote this simple program just to try and check if `slt` or any other comparing instruction can tell me if the value **inside** the string and the integers it represent are bigger then the other one. It's not working and I don't know why.

1. Is this comparison legal or should I turn the strings to real integers?
2. Why doesn't it work? from my understanding the address of each string+offset   should move the correct value too `$t0` and `$t1`.
3. How do I turn this strings to the integers they represent?
4. what can I do in case their are more then 4 integers inside the string? how can I turn "123456" to be the integer in decimal inside the memory? (hex is good too of course)

here's the code: (exited badly after doing the second `lw`)

```
 .data 

    str1: .asciiz "1234"
    str2: .asciiz "1222"

.text
.globl main
 main: 

     lw $t0, str1($t0)
     lw $t1, str2($t1)
     slt $t2, $t0, $t1

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Strings consist of characters that typically are one bytes each. So treating the contents as words makes little sense. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940331/convert-string-of-ascii-digits-to-int-in-mips-assembler

Comment: It should work, but what's in t0 and t1 before lw? Where do you actually load from? If the address is misaligned it may crash - depending if the ARM can handle non-aligned data and if that property is configured on.

Comment: You're essentially asking how to write `atoi` http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/atoi.c.htm