# How to use the ASCII table in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, ascii, mips, mars-simulator

So I'm converting a binary number that the user gives to its decimal equivalent. I finished the conversion without problems, but now I am trying to validate the input. If the user enters any characters besides `1` or `0`, I want to branch to a label that will tell the user that their input is improper. This is what I have right now:

```
ValidateInput:
        lb $s1, userNumber($t8)
        beq $s1, 0, Calculate
        bgt $s1, '1', InvalidInput
        blt $s1, '0', InvalidInput
        addi $t8, $t8, 1
        j ValidateInput
```

I thought I could validate the input by using their ASCII table values, but it now thinks any input I try is improper. Even if I only enter 1s and 0s. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd do `c -= '0'` then unsigned compare to check that `c < 2`, because that leaves you with the `0` or `1` integer value and only needing one branch to validate it.  [double condition checking in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5197264).  I'm not sure what you mean by "table" values; `'0'` and `'1'` already are the ASCII codes as integers.

Comment: What you have looks like it should work, so the problem perhaps lies elsewhere not shown.  What do you see when you single step through some valid input?

Answer (score 0):

So, what I think is that your logic is correct. If the number is greater than 1 or it is less than 0 we must branch to InvalidInput function. But I think bgt and blt are not working properly with string characters.

You can try to change your input to int by following this:

[Convert String of ASCII digits to int in MIPS/Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940331/convert-string-of-ascii-digits-to-int-in-mips-assembler)

And then use the same code